# Updating telerik chart when data change

Tags: c#-4.0, telerik

i have a list of buffers that i display into a telerik radchart.
It displays correctly but when one (or more) of the buffers gets updated i want to update the chart to reflect the new state.
The only thing i'm able to do is recreating the chart from scratch that is a very simple solution yet not very clever...
So my question is if there is a special RadChart type or some option to set to get the chart to autoupdate when one of the collection mapped as DataSeries changes.
Anyone can help?

Here is the code i use to create the chart:

```
private void createChart()
    {
        //Set axis stuff and clear old configuration here

            //Create a dataseries for each values to draw
           foreach (ChannelKeyValueConfiguration channelKeyValue in this.Device.Configuration.ChannelConfigurations)
                {

                    IChannel channel = this.Device.Channels[channelKeyValue.Name];

                    DataSeries serie = new DataSeries();
                    serie.Definition = new LineSeriesDefinition();
                    serie.LegendLabel = channel.Description;

                    int i = 0;
                    int elNumber = channel.Measure.Buffer.Count;   //Neeeded to set xAxis values
                    DateTime minTime = channel.Measure.TimeStamp.Value.AddMilliseconds(-1 * elNumber * channel.Measure.PollingTime);   //Neeeded to set xAxis values

                    foreach (double point in channel.Measure.Buffer)   //Buffer is a Queue<T> that i use as data provider. It updates each x seconds.
                    {
                        i++;
                        serie.Add(new DataPoint() { XValue = minTime.AddMilliseconds( i * channel.Measure.PollingTime).ToOADate(), YValue = point });
                    }

                    RadTimeChart.DefaultView.ChartArea.DataSeries.Add(serie);
                }
            }
```

Then i have an event handler that should update the chart. As i don't know how to achieve it it just recreates it so that it is updated.

```
void StatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate
        {
            createChart();
        }));
    }
```

Please provide some idea on how i can handle updates better.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching and tests i found out that telerik's charts are slow and sometimes used memory start to increse costantly if you do not use Queue to drw your chart.
However they do give some very good [examples in their site](http://www.telerik.com/support/demos/developer-tools-demos.aspx), like the Live Data example, that is pretty much what i was looking for.